# How to add dependency in pyproject.toml from gitlab private package registry

Tags: gitlab, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I am using `poetry` for `dependency` and `packaging` of my project.

One of my python package maintained in `gitlab package registry` . And the pip installation command goes straight forward

`pip install <my_package> --index-url https://__token__:<your_personal_token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple`

But I am unable to add this to my `pyproject.toml` dependency from `gitlab package registry`

This command works for me

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
<my_package> = {git = "https://<token_name>:<>@gitlab.com/lululemon/global-tech-services/retail-engineering-department/dsp/dsp-logging.git"}
```

But its not getting installed from `package registry` rather directly from the `codebase` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix it by adding `poetry source`. Below are the commands to add a package dependency from gitlab package registry

```
poetry source add --secondary foo https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple
poetry config http-basic.foo <token_key> <token_value>
poetry add <package> --source=foo
```

Comment: `--secondary` is now replaced by `--priority supplemental`

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a Gitlab repository `MY_REPO` (arbitary name, internal to `poetry`) whose project ID is `MY_PROJECT_ID`  (indicated on the main page of your project) that provides the python module `MY_MODULE` that you access through a CI/personal token:

```bash
poetry source add --priority supplemental MY_REPO https://MY_GITLAB/api/v4/projects/MY_PROJECT_ID/packages/pypi/simple
poetry config http-basic.MY_REPO __token__ MY_TOKEN
poetry add MY_MODULE --source MY_REPO
```